# Xamarin forms BLE Plugin : GetService,GetDescriptior and Get characteristics method taking much time to load

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugins, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

How to improve performance of services,characterics and descriptor method load time??

From IOT device am getting value of characteristics using Plugin.BLE and put it into foreach loop because it has many data and for each characteristic i will call getdescriptor() method.

It is taking much time to fetch all characteristics with name and value.

Can anyone help how to improve speed of Plugin.BLE for Xamarin forms iOS?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, it’s much more useful to actually post the relevant bits

Comment: It would also be good if you actually told us exactly which "BLE plugin" you are using. And which platform you are using (iOS/Android/...).

Comment: @Emil /@Jason Can we send parallel request to get descriptor in BLE? i noticed when we can't wait for previous BLE command request, descriptor getting null sometimes. So we have to wait for previous command to complete?

Comment: You always need to wait until the previous GATT operation is complete, before you can send a new one.